# Exception caused by other exception

Tags: java, exception

In my application, I am seeing the logs which show

```
Exception1
caused by: Exception2
caused by: Exception3
```

So, If I want to handle this scenario using try-catch, which exception should I give in my catch block? I'am using JDK 1.6, single catch for multiple exceptions is not my solution. Using multi-catch blocks is my last choice.

Comment: If you need to handle different exception in different way, try to catch exception one by one, and implement handle interface. If you'll handle 3 exceptions in one way, just " catch(Exception e)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should catch `Exception1`, since that's the last exception that was thrown.

First `Exception3` was thrown and was caught. The catch block that caught it threw `Exception2`.

Then `Exception2` was caught. The catch block the caught it threw `Exception1`.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a good practice to catch exceptions at a certain level and throw a new exception to provide a better understanding of the context of the exception to the one who catches the exceptions. It is however often useful to include the information from lower level exceptions. This is referred to as [Chained Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html).

You can for example catch an `IOException` while listening to a socket and then throw a (custom) `NetworkException` to differentiate it further while it is passed along to the point where it is caught and possibly rethrown again.

In your case you have to catch only `Exception1`. You can use its causes as hints how to handle the exception though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the top level exception  which is `Exception1` in your case if you want to do generic handling in case of each exception

If you want to do specific stuff for each exception, you should handle each exception individually

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to solve this is to catch every exception that your code causes. **The worsest way** to do that is to catch the general class `Exception`. Like this:

```
try {
     MyObject.doAThingThatCausesAnException();
} catch (Exception ex) {
     //handle your exception here
}
```

Thats **not** what you want to do with your code, because its to general. **Catch every exception, that will be thrown with an own catch block like this.**

```
try {
       MyObject.doAThingThatCausesAnException();
    } catch (NullPointerException ex1)  {
       //handle that exception
    } catch (SQLException ex2) {
       //handle that exception
    } 
    //and so on...
```

I recommend that programming style (second), because you do not forget any exceptions to handle and you can specific divide between the exceptions.